# Is it possible to send a request with the Needle module through another IP?

Tags: node.js, http, request

The request module has the parameter localAddress.

```
 options = { 
         url: "https://ru.tradeskinsfast.com/ajax/botsinventory",
         method: "post",
         headers: {
             'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
             'accept-encoding' : 'gzip :deflate, br',
             'accept-language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
         },
         localAdress: someIp,
}
request(options, function(error, response, body){}
```

How can I do it with the needle module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needle is still a wrapper around Nodes [`http.request`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) like `request` but `needle` doesn't allow you to pass `localAddress` specifically or to pass arbitrary options through to [`http.request`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback).

Needle does support adding a custom [`http.Agent`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_agent) for a request though and the [`agent.createConnection`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_agent_createconnection_options_callback) method supports passing `localAddress` as it uses a [standard socket connect](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_connect_options_connectlistener).

A bit more complex to setup but possible to override the default behaviour.

```
const http = require('http')
const https = require('https')
const needle = require('needle')

class HttpAgentLocal extends http.Agent {

  constructor(options){
    super(options)
    if (options && options.localAddress) this._localAddress = options.localAddress
  }

  createConnection(options, callback){
     if (this._localAddress) options.localAddress = this._localAddress
     return super.createConnection(options, callback)
  }
}

class HttpsAgentLocal extends https.Agent {

  constructor(options){
    this._localAddress = options.localAddress
  }

  createConnection(options, callback){
     options.localAddress = this._localAddress
     return super.createConnection(options, callback)
  }
}


let server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  console.log('request: %s - %s', req.method,req.url, req.connection.remoteAddress)
  res.end('hello\n')
})

server.listen(3121, async ()=> {
  console.log('listening')
  const agent = new HttpAgentLocal({ localAddress: '10.8.8.8' })
  let res = await needle('get','http://localhost:3121/', null, { agent: agent })
  console.log(res.body.toString())
  server.close()
})
```